# get top 10 from my sql query + if check

Tags: php, sql

I'm making an top 10 with the most likes of some pages (don't ask why, this is just an option in my website for links provided from my database)

I'm now doing it on this way, so i can see all the links and the count of facebook likes from the link. Now i want to make an top-10 but don't know how? Do i need to store them all, with a new if statement in an array and then show it.

How do you guys would handle this?

PHP:

```
function get_the_fb_like($paginaurl){

        $url = $paginaurl; // setting a value in $url variable

        $params = 'select comment_count, share_count, like_count from link_stat where url = "'.$url.'"'; // preparing the query for the url

        $component = urlencode( $params ); // prepare the url for fetching the information from facebook

        $url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q='.$component; // constructed url

        $fbLIkeAndSahre = json_decode( file_get_contents_curl( $url ) ); // convert the json from our response to object

        $getFbStatus = $fbLIkeAndSahre->data['0'];

        return $getFbStatus->like_count; // return the number of like of the passed url

    }

    $result = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM photos where geupload = :maandenjaar AND goedgekeurd = :goed');

    $result->execute(array(':maandenjaar' => $maandenjaar, ':goed' => 'ja'));

    $numrows = $result->rowCount();

    if($numrows != 0){
        foreach ($result as $row) {

            if(get_the_fb_like('?photo='.$row['id'].'') != 0){
                echo '
                            <div class="imgwrap">
                                <a href="'.$row['id'].'" title="'.$row['caption'].'"><img src="'.$row['location'].'" alt="'.$row['beschrijving'].'" /></a><br />
                                <p>Likes: '.get_the_fb_like('?photo='.$row['id'].'').'</p>
                            </div>
                        ';
            }

        }   
    }else{
        echo 'Er zijn geen afbeeldingen deze maand';
    }
```

**EDIT:**

You guys don't really understand my question, sorry. I'll try to explain it a bit more.
I have a database with picture id's. That ppl can like.

For the like count, i use the facebook api by url to get the like count of an url. 
So there is no way that i can LIMIT 10 from my database, because i don't store the count's in my database.

Comment: limit 10 from facebook then

Comment: It needs to be the HIGHEST count, for a TOP-10. So i can't just limit 10.. the script would just take the 10 first..

Comment: thats why you order by like_count

Comment: Ow yeah really sorry! Didn't look that good. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$params = 'select comment_count, share_count, like_count from link_stat where url = "'.$url.'" ORDER BY like_count desc LIMIT 10'; // preparing the query for the url
```

Comment: See my edit for more info, cuz this is not going to work i think.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of your links are stored in the `link_stat` table which it looks like the case from your question, you can just do a sorted query of the table and return the first 10 results.

```
SELECT *
FROM link_stat
ORDER BY like_count
LIMIT 0, 10
```